# How do I calculate i, i1, i2 and v2?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

I'm unable to figure out how to use the current dependant voltage source in KVL

The following are the equations I've found, up till now:
20i+V2=10, 
V2=50i1, 
20i+50i1=10,
i=i1+i2

Comment: Use mesh analysis. Update your question with the equations you found and we will help you along.

Comment: **updating** your question means **editing** it, @Aimen: That way, others don't have to read all through the comments here.

Comment: You're on the right way. There is another way to write out V2, i.e. using the components between nodes b and c and between c and d. (BTW, you need to use **2 spaces** at the end of a line to start text on a new line)

Comment: What happened to the 25 ohm resistor? It is not in your equations. (And no, in this circuit you can't ignore it)

Comment: So equation 1 can be written as 20i+5i1+25i2=10  and equation 2 as 45i1-25i2=0

Comment: Can't we write 5i1+25i2 as V2?

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to in order to solve the circuit.

Comment: Alright but I'm not getting anywhere with these equations at the moment. How do I further solve this?

Comment: Use math : you have two equations with two unknowns.

Comment: Try to write down all your equations: ```mesh 1: a+b+c ``` and ```mesh 2: d+f etc ``` and (if you used I and/or V2) ```I=i1+i2 ```. and ```V2=5i1+25i2 ```. Substitue the last two equations in the first 2. Now, you find 2 equations with 2 unknowns. Then, solve the result

Comment: Are these the answers? i=0.36A,  i1=0.094A,  i2=0.17A and V2=4.717V?

Comment: @Aimen no they are not!

Comment: @Jan Yes I know, I got the right answers now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4GdpU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can write:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag1$$

Using KVL, we can write:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{a}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{V}_\text{x}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2=\alpha\text{I}_1
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Using some Mathematica code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Va - V1)/R1, I2 == V2/R2, I3 == V1/R3, 
   Vx == V1 - V2 == α*I1}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, V2, Vx}]]
```

Using Your values we get:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (10 - V1)/20, I2 == V2/25, I3 == V1/50, 
   Vx == V1 - V2 == 5*I1}, {I1, I2, I3, V1, V2, Vx}]]
```

Which gives:

```
{{I1 -> 1/4, I2 -> 3/20, I3 -> 1/10, V1 -> 5, V2 -> 15/4, Vx -> 5/4}}
```

Which approximate to:

```
{{I1 -> 0.25, I2 -> 0.15, I3 -> 0.1, V1 -> 5., V2 -> 3.75, 
  Vx -> 1.25}}
```

Comment: Alright, I got it. Thank you very much for the help 

Comment: @Aimen You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: Please stop giving away homework solutions.